# Show that $\vert w\bar{z}+\bar{w}z\vert\leq 2\vert wz\vert$ where $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

> Show that $\vert w\bar{z}+\bar{w}z\vert\leq 2\vert wz\vert$ where $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$

So I let $z=x+iy$, $w=a+ib$

Then from the left hand side of the inequality I get:

$\vert w\bar{z}+\bar{w}z\vert$

$=\vert (ax-iay+ixb+by)+(ax+iay-ixb+by)\vert$

$=\vert 2ax+2by\vert$

Applying triangle inequality I end up with:

$\leq 2\vert ax\vert + 2\vert by\vert$

If I expand the right hand side I get:

$2\vert ax-by+iay+ixb\vert$

Im not sure how to determine the first is less than or equal to the second now. It seems what I need to show is that $\vert ax\vert + \vert by\vert\leq \vert ax-by+i(ay+xb)\vert$

Comment: If either $w$ or $z$ is zero the inequality reduces to $0 \le 0\,$. Otherwise $wz\ne0\,$, then dividing by $|wz| \gt 0\,$ and using the triangle inequality: $\displaystyle 
\left|\frac{\bar z}{z}+\frac{\bar w}{w}\right| \le \left|\frac{\bar z}{z}\right|+\left|\frac{\bar w}{w}\right|=1+1\,$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simpler to work directly with the complex numbers instead of calculating with the cartesian coordinates. Using

- the triangle inequality,
- the fact that the absolute value of a product is equal to the product of the absolute values, and
- the fact that a complex number and its conjugate have the same absolute value

one gets
$$
| w\bar{z}+\bar{w}z | \le | w\bar{z}|+|\bar{w}z | 
= | w|\cdot |\bar{z}|+|\bar{w}| \cdot |z | \\
= | w|\cdot |z|+|w| \cdot |z | = 2|z||w| = 2|zw| \, .
$$

One can also argue that
$$
| w\bar{z}+\bar{w}z | = |2 \operatorname{Re}(w \bar{z})| 
= 2 |\operatorname{Re}(w \bar{z})|  \le 2 | w \bar{z}|
= 2|zw | \, .
$$

Of course
$$ \tag{*}
\vert ax\vert + \vert by\vert\leq \vert ax-by+i(ay+xb)\vert
$$
can also be verified: The right-hand side is
$$
\sqrt{(ax-by)^2+(ay+bx)^2} = \sqrt{(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)}
$$
which shows that $(*)$ is just the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the down vote. Voting up to compensate, until the anonymous down voter explains his down vote.

Comment: @Thomas I agree. I have done the same. Downvoting a good answer like this one is a shame.